# Select State based on event listener

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to create an interactive map of the US, whereby when a location is clicked on the state that that point lies in will become shaded. 
I have created an event listener that will draw the layer upon clicking, but I can't figure out how to have the Fusion Table only grab the state data. 
I have tried with ST_INTERSECTS.

Is this possible with the fusion table query? would it be better/more efficient to create a lookup table of my own with polygons? 
Any help is greatly appreciated, very new to the fusiontables and google maps api!

thanks

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select:  'geometry',
            from: '17aT9Ud-YnGiXdXEJUyycH2ocUqreOeKGbzCkUw',
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',Circle(event.latLng,5000))' 
          }
        });
        layer.setMap(map);
```

I can confirm that this works, and only selects California.

```
        where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(37.3242,-121.9806),1))'
```

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT! You have to create vars for the event.latLng coords like this:

```
clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
clickLng = event.latLng.lng();
```

(I don't declare them as 'var' because I want them to not be persistent, see below)

and then construct the where filter like this:

```
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + clickLat + ',' + clickLng + '),1))'
```

watch those quotes!

Now, I want each click to clear any previous layer, because I want just one state outlined, this is accomplished by adding a simple check:

```
if (typeof clickLat !== 'undefined') {
             layer.setMap(null)
             }
```

I also don't want this layer to be clickable, because if it is, a huge block of the geometry appears, and I have other information I want displayed anyway, this is accomplished by setting the clickability of the FusionTablesLayer to 'false'.

Here is the complete code, fyi:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
   if (typeof clickLat !== 'undefined') {
                 layer.setMap(null)
                 }   
   clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
   clickLng = event.latLng.lng();
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select:  'geometry',
            from: '17aT9Ud-YnGiXdXEJUyycH2ocUqreOeKGbzCkUw',
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + clickLat + ',' + clickLng + '),1))'
          },
          styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                        strokeColor: "#5e3cff",
                        strokeWeight: 3,
                        fillColor: "#9d9d9d",
                        fillOpacity: 0.2,
            }
          }],
          clickable: false
        });
        layer.setMap(map);

});
```